# Expressão Regular em Java

Tags: java, string, regex

Estou programando em Java e preciso filtrar um String a partir de uma regex usando o método `matches()`.

Posso aceitar letras (a-z) ou números (0-9),  onde esse número pode ter 1 ou n dígitos. Estou usando a seguinte regex: `[A-Z|a-z|\d{n} ]`.

O filtro das letras está funcionando perfeitamente, porém o dos números não está aceitando um número com mais de um digito (`10` por exemplo ), enquanto números de um único digito estão passando. 
Não tenho muito conhecimento de regex, mas pelo o que li, essa deveria funcionar.

Answer (score 6):

Quando você usa colchetes numa regex, você está pedindo para ela casar **um** e somente um caractere, dentre a lista indicada. Exceto pelos caracteres especiais (`-`, `\` e `^` [no início]), tudo o que estiver dentro dos colchetes é interpretado literalmente. Isso significa que a regex:

```
[A-Z|a-z|\d{n} ]
```

Vai aceitar as strings:

```
"A"
"B"
"Z"
"|"
"4"
"{"
"}"
" "
```

E vai rejeitar qualquer string com mais de um caractere. Se você quer uma regex que case duas ou mais regras combinadas com **ou** (`|`), você tem que fazer isso fora dos colchetes:

```
([A-Z]|[a-z]|\d{n})
```

ou simplificando:

```
([A-Za-z]|\d{n})
```

Nota: você diz "1 ou n dígitos", mas nesse caso ela aceitaria **exatamente** `n` dígitos. Se o que você quer é mesmo 1 ou n, dessa forma deve funcionar:

```
([A-Za-z\d]|\d{n})
```

Assumindo que `n` é um número. Mas numa segunda leitura, me parece que o que você quer é "um ou mais dígitos", seria isso? Se for, o correto é:

```
([A-Za-z]|\d+)
```

[Exemplo no ideone](http://ideone.com/JpxNEj).

---

P.S. Em Java, os parênteses são opcionais quando se usa `|`, uma vez que cada método do [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) (`matches`, `lookingAt`, `find`) atua de uma forma diferente (eliminando a necessidade de `^` e `$` para casar a string inteira). Mas deve-se ter cuidado com a precedência desse operador. Por exemplo, a regex:

```
^[A-Za-z]|\d+$
```

É equivalente a:

```
(^[A-Za-z])|(\d+$)
```

E não a:

```
^([A-Za-z]|\d+)$
```

E, portanto, casa `aa` ou `###1`. [Exemplo](http://rubular.com/r/HKpSQ6PNwW), [exemplo correto](http://rubular.com/r/Z9iOwlQGmp) (Usando `?:` para evitar criar um [grupo de captura](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)).

Comment: Verdade, procurei mais um pouco na literatura e encontrei essa restrição do colchete. Quanto ao parêntese obrigatório, não acredito que seja obrigatório em Java quando se usa |.  Também consegui resolver o problema usando a classe Regex disponível na utils do Java.  Muito obrigado pela resposta!

Comment: O interessante é que mesmo usando colchetes, usando a classe Regex, foram aceitos dois dígitos, deve ser algum tratamento interno. Ficou da seguinte forma (declaração dos Pattern ) :                                                                            Pattern pattAlphaNum = Pattern.compile("[A-Z|a-z|\\d+]");
Pattern pattAlpha = Pattern.compile("[A-Z|a-z]");
Pattern pattNum = Pattern.compile("[\\d+]");

Comment: @NatanaelRamos Como você está usando esses `Pattern`s? Testei eles no ideone, veja o [resultado](http://ideone.com/JpxNEj). P.S. Obrigado por apontar a questão dos parênteses obrigatórios, atualizei minha resposta.

Comment: Minha implementação ficou um pouco diferente, segui os passos apresentados no site <http://ocpsoft.org/opensource/guide-to-regular-expressions-in-java-part-1/>

Fiz o [codigo](http://ideone.com/angwnE), se puder dar uma olhada. 
Mas ainda tem um problema, a String "2a" por exemplo, é reconhecida pelo pattNum e pelo pattAlpha. Será essa restrição dos colchetes? Pois tirando eles o resultado ainda é o mesmo.

Comment: @NatanaelRamos A função do `find` é encontrar todo casamento em uma string longa. Por exemplo, se você usar o padrão `\\d+` na string `bla bla 10 bla 4 bla 123 bla` ele vai encontrar o `10` primeiro, o `4` depois e o `123` por último. Como `2a` contém um número e uma letra, então: 1) ambos os padrões reconhecem ela via `find`; 2) nenhum deles deve reconhecê-la via `matches`; 3) apenas o `pattNum` deve reconhecê-la via `lookingAt`.